# What is the ratio of $A_1$ and $A_2$

Tags: volume, surfaces

[image]

The sphere is formed by disrupting the cube that is made by play dough with $r = 2$. 
The surface area of sphere is $A_1$ and surface area of cube is $A_2$

What is the ratio of $\frac {A_1}{A_2}$? Use the approximation $\pi\approx3$.

As first, I thought that

$$\text{Volume of sphere}=\text{Volume of cube}$$

However, I'm stuck here. I mean I don't know what to do more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

volume of a sphere is given by $$V_1=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$$ and the cube $$V_2=a^3$$
and forhter $$A_1=4\pi r^2$$ (surface of a sphere) and $$A_2=6a^2$$ for a dice.
to find $$a$$ solve the equation $$a^3=\frac{4}{3}\pi\cdot 2^3$$ for $a$
we find $$a=2\sqrt[3]{\frac{4\pi}{3}}$$

Comment: I know it but couldn't build the correct equation. Also, I couldn't find $a$.

Comment: I still couldn't find what $a$ is.

Comment: @Lagranian. Value of $a$ is $\sqrt[3]{\frac{32}3\pi}$ which is approximately $3.223983908032939281433933693278569877889228144647723111384584150757901930114290548492311299479004868$.

Comment: Oh, I finally found that $a^3 = 48$.

Comment: ok and now take the cube root

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I'm confused at this step $a=2\sqrt[3]{\frac{4\pi}{3}}$.

Comment: this is the same like $$a=\sqrt[3]{\frac{8\cdot 4\pi}{3}}$$ just a simplification

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Where did that $8$ come from?

Comment: it is $$8=2^3$$

Comment: Before it, I don't know what cube root means. I think the problem would be that.

Comment: i hope you know it now the cube root

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $a=2\sqrt[3]{\frac{4\pi}{3}}$ How do you solve this cube root problem? I can get it if you show. (First time I've seen).

Comment: it is the same like $$2\sqrt[3]{\frac{4\pi}{3}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{8\cdot 4\pi}{3}}$$

Comment: I'm getting wrong answer.

Comment: why did you get a wrong answer? in which step?

Comment: $a=\sqrt[3]{\frac{8\cdot 4\pi}{3}}$ At this step. It becomes $\sqrt[3]{\frac{32}3\pi}$ but couldn't work it out more.

Comment: it is $$\approx 3.223983908032939281433933693278569877889228144647723111384584150757901930114290548492311299479004868$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner However, I'm getting $\approx 3.1748021039364$.

Comment: hm ok if $$\pi=3$$

Answer (score 1):

You already managed to find that
$$a^3=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$$
So
$$\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)^3=\frac{4}{3}\pi$$
We also know that
$$A_1=6a^2$$
and
$$A_2=4\pi r^2$$
You should be able to proceed from here using a similar trick on the area.

Comment: I still couldn't find what $a$ is.

Comment: There is no need to find $a$ since you are only finding $\frac{A_1}{A_2}$.

Comment: And technically you can already find $a$ from my second line since we know $r=2$.

Comment: We need to know what $a$ is. By the way, I'm wondering how to.

Comment: Use my second line

Answer (score 0):

Because of The sphere is formed by disrupting the cube a=2r

48/96=1/2 That's the answer

Comment: Volumes are not equal!